# Mutex of multi process

Tags: ipc, mutex

I want to find solution for my problem: I have some processes that use shared memory for sharing data. For synchronization, I use mutex. But when a process which locks mutex crashes, all the other processes also crash. So how to avoid this problem?

Comment: The process that crashed first is probably the one that created the shared memory, so when it crashed, the shared memory is lost. So all other processes no longer accessing to a valid memory address and they don't have sufficient error handling.

Comment: In case the process created the shared memory did not crash? the crashed process is another?

Comment: If the process that created the shared memory didn't crash, the other should not crash unless there are other causes such as corrupted data in shared memory.

Comment: if one process could crashed while writting data into shared memory (example: segmentation fault), so all the other were blocked. So I want to find a solution that the crash of each process when locked mutex didn't affect the other?

Comment: Crashed process after taking mutex ownership is same as without calling `ReleaseMutex` at all. What's needed is a better error handling in case unexpected result occurs. Never assume that after communication is established, everything will go smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on which mutex implementation you're using (e.g. WinAPI, pthreads...).

For example, in WinAPI, if a process holding a mutex dies without releasing it, other processes waiting for that mutex receives a return value of `WAIT_ABANDONED` from functions such as `WaitForSingleObject`. It's possible you aren't dealing with it.

Other libraries may have their own quirks and implementation details, and should be reviewed accordingly.

Also make sure you're talking about multi-processes rather than multi-therads, because in the case of multiple threads under a single process, under some implementations, if the first thread of that process dies - so do all threads in that process.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about multi-processes. I use pthread. I found this function: `pthread_mutex_timedlock_np`. Is this thing can help me?